# Word meaning "only known to experts"

Tags: synonyms

Looking for a word meaning "only known to experts".  Such as esoteric or byzantine.

Comment: A word request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s more of a request for guesses or ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A word request should include details of research you’ve done, solutions you’ve rejected, and why, the desired connotation, formality, part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 4):

I like the meta quality of this question. So how about:

> ### recherché
>
> /rəˌSHerˈSHā/
>   adjective
>   rare, exotic, or obscure.
>   "**a few linguistic terms are perhaps a bit recherché for the average readership**"
>   synonyms: obscure, rare, esoteric, abstruse, arcane, recondite, exotic, strange, unusual, unfamiliar, out of the ordinary

From Oxford Dictionaries Online ([ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/)).

Answer (score 4):

[jargon noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon#synonyms):

> jar·​gon | \ˈjär-gən,  -ˌgän\
>   Definition of jargon (Entry 1 of 2)
>   1 : the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group
>   sports jargon
>   2 : obscure and often pretentious language marked by circumlocutions and long words an academic essay filled with jargon